# Stuck on derivative of inverse function problem!

Tags: derivatives, inverse-function

I am super stuck on a problem. I am on the chapter of my calculus book on the derivatives on inverse functions but I can't figure it out.

[Note: I am writing the inverse of $f$ as $f^{-1}$] 
The problem is:

> Find $(f^{-1})'(5)$ where $f(x) = 3x^3 + 4x^2 + 6x + 5$.

The back of the book says the answer is $1/6 $

I know that $(f^{-1})'(a)$ = $1 / f'( f^1(a) )$ 
I used symlab to find $f(x) = 5$ and it gives me:
$-(2/3) * (+ or -) i(\sqrt{14} / 3)$ 
which is a complex number so that can't be what I'm looking for.

Then i tried implicit derivation to find $dy/dx$ and that just gave me: 
$9x^2 + 8x + 6$ 
And plugging in $5$ gives a number way too big.

I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong. I've watched all kinds of videos on this and reread the chapter a bunch of times and still can't get it. They always find the equation (f^-1). But if you just find that equation, then why not just take it's derivative rather than the weird [ $1 / f'( f^{-1}(x))$ ] ? 
I must be missing some basic idea of this, but I don't know what.

I really appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the polynomial $f(x)=3x^3 + 4x^2 + 6x + 5$ is a strictly increasing function. Hence $f$ has an inverse and $f^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$.

Now $f(0)=5$. What is $f'(0)$? Is this value related with derivative of $f^{-1}$ at $5$?